# No output for `python.exe -c 'print("hello")'`

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn python and stumbled on what seems to be another stupid error on my part.

With version 2.7.3 that I downloaded from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/) I do not get any output for a simple program with `-c`. I *do* get output with the 2.6.8 release from cygwin.

What am I missing?

```
> c:\Python27\python.exe --version
Python 2.7.3

> c:\Python27\python.exe -c 'print("hello")'

> c:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello")
hello
>>> exit()

> c:\cygwin\bin\python2.6.exe --version
Python 2.6.8

> c:\cygwin\bin\python2.6.exe -c 'print("hello")'
hello

> c:\cygwin\bin\python2.6.exe
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jun  9 2012, 11:30:32)
[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

Comment: I would try printing to a file just to see what will happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it without the single quotes around the program:

```
python -c print(\"hello\")
```

With the single quotes, I guess it interprets the input as a string so doesn't do the print. You also need to escape the double quotes in the program itself.

**Edit:**

You don't need to escape single quotes, so you can do this instead:

```
python -c print('hello')
```

or

```
python -c "print('hello')"
```

(which is the original example, just with the quote types swapped)

Comment: aargh. the problem is not with python but that I forget how cmd.exe works. I will accept this in 2 minutes.

Comment: I doubt you're the first or last person to do this, so it's a useful question to have here :-)

Comment: Going by the upvotes (both your and mine) I certainly don't seem to be the only one :)